# Set PS1 with subcommand that prints colors

Tags: bash, sh, prompt, git-bash

When putting ANSI color codes in `PS1`, they need to be surrounded with `\[\]` or else the prompt can get confused about where the editable part of the line starts. However, when a subcommand (`$()`) prints colors, the `\[\]` escapes are always being written literally to the prompt...and with long enough commands in my history, the prompt gets confused.

Here's an example:

```
ps1test() {
    ps1sub() {
        printf '\[\033[32m\]Hello!\[\033[0m\]'
    }
    PS1='$(ps1sub) \$ '
}
```

Expected:

```
$ ps1test
Hello! $
```

Actual (`bash` installed by Git for Windows):

```
$ ps1test
\[\]Hello!\[\] $
```

How can I get my shell to interpret the `\[\]` escapes from a subcommand?

Comment: Rather that using raw color codes, it is *much* cleaner to use `tput`.

Comment: Cleaner yes, but too many calls to `tput` can significantly slow down the shell. At least on Windows. But anyway, the color codes in the question are only an example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Only `\[`s in the literal string are interpreted. `\[`s resulting from embedded expansions are not.

The easiest way to get around it is to have `PROMPT_COMMAND` set a `PS1` to a new literal value each time:

```
updateps1() {
    ps1sub() {
        printf '\[\033[32m\]Hello $RANDOM!\[\033[0m\]'
    }
    PS1="$(ps1sub) \\\$ "
}

PROMPT_COMMAND='updateps1'
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're trying to create a dynamic prompt, you're likely to have an easier time setting the `PS1` value via a function invoked as `PROMPT_COMMAND`, e.g.:

```
ps1test() {
  ps1sub() {
        printf '\[\033[32m\]Hello!\[\033[0m\]'
    }
    PS1="$(ps1sub)"' \$ ' # notice the double-quote
}
PROMPT_COMMAND=ps1test
```

This renders correctly as `Hello! $`  for me.

I use [prompt.gem](https://github.com/dimo414/prompt.gem) to render my prompt, you can take a look at how it [configures `PROMPT_COMMAND`](http://hg.mwdiamond.com/prompt.gem/src/ded518a/functions.sh#functions.sh-165) for some inspiration.

Answer (score 0):

This is exactly the right use case for `eval`:

```
ps1test() {  
    ps1sub() {  
        printf '\[\033[31m\]Hello!\[\033[0m\]';     
    };  
    eval PS1="'$(ps1sub) \$ '"; 
}
```

Comment: Only if the result of `ps1sub` doesn't change depending on the context.

Comment: In this case, it's equivalent to `PS1="$(ps1sub) \$ "` but more fragile